# Swift SWRevealViewController not working

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a Side Menu with SWRevealViewController.
I'm working trough a tutorial but it's not working for me. Xcode gives me an error like "2017-10-19 08:31:36.332312+0200 SideMenu[61861:7944396] Unknown class SWRevealViewController in Interface Builder file."

I included both SWRevealViewController files and a Bridging Header file.
I set the Initial View Controller to SWRevealViewController like shown in the picture. [image]

I set both segues to sw_rear and sw_front and set the Class for this to SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController.
sw_rear
[image]
and sw_front
[image]

And I also set a segue from my TableView to the Navigation Controller with Class SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController.
[image]

But all I'm getting for output is a white blank screen and the error mentioned. Can anybody help me please, I have no idea with this error.

Answer (score 3):

I forgot to set the target for the included SWRevealViewController files...Stupid error